# JBAS014601 Error booting the container

Tags: jboss7.x

when I run my project on eclipse it appears this

```
21:24:52,883 Infos [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
21:24:53,056 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
21:24:53,103 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" starting
21:24:53,442 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] JBAS014601: Error booting the container: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:161) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:125) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:187) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:261) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:155) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,1]
Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:1.2}server'
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:108) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:117) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    ... 4 more

21:24:53,443 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015950: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" stopped in 4ms
```

my eclipse is luna and my jboss is 7.1
please help me to solve this problem 
thank you very much

Comment: If you read the error message it's quite clear there's an issue win your XML configuration. I don't suggest editing the raw XML file. If you need to make configuration changes use the web console or CLI.

Comment: I didnt understand can u say for me step by step cause I am new on eclipse

Comment: Not sure about eclipse, but the configuration has an error. Likely the standalone.xml file.